# VBA code to call different macro depending on part of Worksheet name

Tags: excel, loops, if-statement, worksheet, vba

I am working on a macro that will cycle through all of the sheets in the active workbook and will then clear a certain part of a particular worksheet, based on whether one of the relevant keywords is contained in the worksheet name. In each case the worksheet name will be different, but any I want to clear will contain one of the key words below.

I have set up a separate macro to clear the range of cells in each case. If the Worksheet name does not contain any of the keywords, I want the macro to move onto the next worksheet.

My ultimate aim is to be able to apply this to numerous different workbooks, as the project I am working on is split by region, with a separate Excel file per region.

The code I have been trying is below. There are no errors appearing when I run the code, the code does not seem to run either, in fact nothing at all happens!

Any guidance or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Loop_Customer_Sheets()

    Dim ws As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    For i = 1 To ws
        If ActiveSheet.Name Like "*ABC*" Then
            Call ABCInfoClear
        ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name Like "*DEF*" Then
            Call DEFInfoClear
        ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name Like "*GHI*" Then
            Call GHIInfoClear
        Else:
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### "Nothing at all happens" - fixing the issue with your code:

Your issue is that you are looping through the *number* of sheets, but you are only checking the `ActiveSheet`, which never changes! Replace your code with

```
ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
For i = 1 To ws
    With ActiveWorkbook.WorkSheets(i)
        If .Name Like "*ABC*" Then
            ABCInfoClear
        ElseIf .Name Like "*DEF*" Then
            DEFInfoClear
        ElseIf ActiveSheet.Name Like "*GHI*" Then
            GHIInfoClear
        End If
    End With
Next i
```

Note: you don't need the `Call` keyword, you can just call subs as presented above.

---

#### Alternative solutions

A better option than having numerous macros might be to create a generic sub like

```
Sub ClearRangeInSheet(rangeAddress As String, sh As WorkSheet)
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = sh.Range(rangeAddress)
    myRange.ClearContents
    ' Any other cell clearing code e.g. for formatting here
End Sub
```

Then call in the loop

```
Dim wsCount as Long
wsCount = ActiveWorkbook.WorkSheets.Count
For i = 1 to wsCount
    With ActiveWorkbook
        If .WorkSheets(i).Name Like "*ABC*" Then
            ' Always pass ".WorkSheets(i)", but change the range address as needed
            ClearRangeInSheet("A1:A20", .WorkSheets(i))
        ElseIf ' Other worksheet name conditions ...

        End If
    End With
Next I
```

---

As suggested in the comments, you could ditch *indexing* the sheets, and just loop through the sheet objects themselves:

```
Dim wksht as WorkSheet
For Each wksht In ActiveWorkbook.WorkSheets
    If wksht.Name Like "*ABC*" Then
        ' Always pass wksht but change the range address as needed
        ClearRangeInSheet("A1:A20", wksht)
    ElseIf ' Other worksheet name conditions ...

    End If
Next wksht
```

Comment: Maybe use `For Each ws In ActiveWorkBook.Worksheets` (with ws defined as a worksheet) rather than a `For...Next` loop.

Comment: @Darren, definitely an option, I was just trying to stay as close as possible to the OP's layout to keep things simple. I've included a good example of your suggestion in an edit.

Comment: Hi Wolfie, thanks a million for taking the time to give such an in-depth answer! I have replaced my code with the one you have outlined (I've avoided adding the shortcuts you suggested for now, but will definitely add them in future). The macro is working now, but runs all of the **InfoClear** macros on the same sheet and does not transition to the next sheet. Would there be common reasons why this might happen? I am currently reviewing what I entered with your example above, but I'm not seeing any difference so far.

Comment: To answer that, I would have to see an example of one of your `InfoClear` macros, please edit it into your question... It's likely you're using `ActiveSheet` or similar within each of the macros, where you instead want to pass the relevant sheet as an input argument to those subs.

Comment: You were spot on, upon review I remembered that my Clear macros were just recordings of me selecting and clearing the relevant cells, so they were locked to the active sheet. I've incorporated your generic sub into my macro and now everything is working perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah glad that was an easy fix, no worries :)